# Error in getting the network adapter handle - CreateFile

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

I am trying to get the handle to the network adapter driver by calling the CreateFile function. It is returning **error code 3** which indicates **The system cannot find the path specified**

Below is the code

```
tun_fd = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\Global\\INTELPRO_{7A1C62D4-2FE2-49D6-9090-DFA5FF1F8395}", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);

if (tun_fd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   printf("handle failed with error: %ld\n", GetLastError());   
}
```

I also ran the WinObj tool and took a snap of the network driver object which I am trying to access [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4BgH.png)

Any changes to be done in giving the path?

Comment: Why the `\\.` is used to prefix the path?

Comment: Should'n't it be `L"\\\\?\\Global\\...` instead of `"L"\\\\.\\Global\\...`

Comment: Jabberwocky: I tried this as well but of no luck

Comment: Changed the charset setting in the properties and worked